# Why is CakePHP 3 plugin error template not displaying

Tags: templates, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I recently upgraded to CakePHP 3. I want to use themes so I created a plugin using cake bake plugin PlgTest. This got created successfully. I set the theme variable in  the AppController. The application now uses the templates created in the plugin's template directory. So far so good.

However when an exception is thrown like a ForbiddenException (403) in the CSRFComponent, the template that gets displayed is the default one and not the one that's in the plugin's template directory.

I was expecting the plugin's PlgTest/src/Template/Error/error400.ctp to be displayed instead the default /Template/Error/error400.ctp is displayed. Why? Is there a quick solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: Because you have no [error controller](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/errors.html#creating-a-custom-controller-to-handle-exceptions) and the default one from the core doesn't extend app-controller.

Answer (score 0):

Found a good solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33103872/is-it-possible-to-use-appcontroller-on-error-pages-cakephp-3-1) in case do someone need

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;
use Cake\Event\Event;

class ErrorController extends AppController
{
    public function beforeRender(Event $event)
    {
        parent::beforeRender($event);
        $this->viewBuilder()->templatePath('Error');
    }
}
```

The creditis goes to "Test Testington"